# Using "BY", "UNTIL" and "TILL" with Future Perfect tense

Tags: prepositions, future-perfect

Is it correct to state that "by" is used with Future Perfect tense in affirmative sentences, and "until" / "till" are interchangeable and used only in  negative statements? And what about interrogative ones ("by" similar to affirmative)?

I'm still not sure is there any real difference, though I've tried to clear it up.

Comment: No, it's not true. There's nothing unusual about, say, *I'll be here until 5 o'clock*, and I see no "negation" there. Of course, I could also say *I **won't** be there until 5 o'clock*, and I could replace ***until*** with ***by*** in both cases to "reverse" the meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, but what about Future Perfect tense?

Comment: What about it? ***By** the time you can understand this sentence, you **will have understood** how it works.* Alternatively, ***Until** you can understand this sentence, you **will not have understood** how it works.* In those examples, the *semantics* make it easier to pair ***by*** with a "positive" assertion, and ***until*** with a negative one. *But **until** you can understand **this** example, you **will have been limited** in your grasp of how English tenses can validly be used*. Your *by=affirmative, until=negative* idea is largely spurious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't have finished X until|by...  <sup>grammatical</sup>

I won't have begun it until|by ... <sup>grammatical</sup>

I will have finished X until... <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

I will have begun it until ... <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

You cannot express a completion with a lifespan.

But you can express a *process* with a lifespan:

> He will have eaten it until it made him sick. He cannot control
>   himself with chocolate cake.
>
> Knowing him, he will have played that guitar until his fingers blistered.
>
> He will have waited there until the lights went out.

Comment: +1 - Is it wrong to say : `until his fingers are blistered?`

Comment: I think the present tense is not impossible there, though it sounds marginal to me.

Comment: Thanks. Since i've been using it for a long time and no one told me it's wrong. I wondered if they were laughing at me inside! :D

Comment: @TRomano, so as far as I understand, I'm able to say: `"I will not have done this task until / by you come to me tomorrow"`. And `"I will have been doing it untill you come"`? According to your adjustments? Moreover I used to think we use Present Simple with time conjunctions such as : `"after"`, `"until"`, `"before"`, `"by the time"`, `"as soon as"`, so I agree with Jack Johansson's question.

Comment: It seems to me all your final three "process" examples refer to *what he has **already** done* - but although strictly speaking we don't know this for sure, that's what we ***will/would*** establish with certainty *if we were to investigate the matter more thoroughly*. This is somewhat different to a "real" future reference such as, say, *By midnight tonight he will have waited there for twelve hours* (which idiomatically we'd be more likely to express with the continuous *...he will have been waiting*).

Comment: They don't refer to "what he has *already* done" but to "what he will have done" as of a certain time in the future.

Comment: @Anthony Voronkov:  There is no rule which says the present simple is the only tense that can be used with "after", "before", "as soon as", "by the time". Good that you don't think so now, but only *used to think* so.